# How do you install the HipChat plugin for GrayLog2?

Tags: plugins, graylog2, hipchat

I was directed to the Graylog2 HipChat Plugin available [HERE](https://www.graylog2.org/plugins/54636955e4b0edc7c721c2cb/hipchat) and followed the (rather simple) steps regarding its installation.

Unfortunately after restarting Graylog2-server nothing seems to be picked up regarding the plugin. Stream settings do not have the HipChat options as in the installation steps screenshot, and i cannot find anything in the log files about the plugin not loading/breaking.

I have amended the /etc/graylog2.conf so that the 'plugin_dir' is an absolute path to the plugin folder location. But yet it is as if Graylog2 just does not recognize that a .jar file is there.

This is my first attempt at installing a Graylog2 plugin.
Is this the correct way of installing the hipchat plugin, but if not how do you install the HipChat plugin for GrayLog2?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Graylog plugins - tried two different versions of Graylog and Elasticsearch via an upgrade. Plugins not loading before or after. Can't see anything in logs. Tried absolute path and multiple types of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I got the Slack and HipChat plugins to work via dropping the jars in the plugin top-level directory. Not the sub-level inputs, outputs, or transports directory and plugin directory is an absolute path:  /opt/plugin. Hope it helps.

Amazon CloudTrail plugin is working on my production server as well, although there are still an issue with dev.

Comment: also do not forget to chown your plugin directory if you have created a graylog user.